# Remove Identity/Account/Register

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application and I am new to it.

I face with a problem in this project which cause duplicate links. In ASP.NET Core, there is Identity area which we can scaffold pages like registration, sign up and etc.

But I want to clean up my urls and I want to simplify them. So I have written my own `AccountController` with `Login` and `Register` action methods.

Therefore users can access to sign up action both from `Account/Register` and `Identity/Account/Register`.

How should I disable access to `Identity` self generated links?

Comment: You could have just changed Identity urls, which would have been simpler. Look up "scaffold ASP.NET Core Identity" for examples

Comment: Your project which contains default login module of identity, maybe there will be a `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in the shared folder, you may check it.